# RegExp - How to return a single row of answers instead of multiple rows of answers

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have a RegExp

```
/h.*e.*l.*l.*o.*/i
```

And I have my paragraph that its being run on.

```
Hey look at that lion!
```

The result is this:

```
answer[0] = Hey look at that lion!
answer[1] = H
answer[2] = e
answer[3] = l
answer[4] = l
answer[5] = o
```

I was wondering if I could get a result like this:

```
answer[0] = Hey look at that lion!
answer[1] = Hello
```

by **only** changing my RegExp. Maybe using grouping or something? And if the answer to that question is no, then what are my other options? I really don't want to loop over the answer and string it together either, but if that's the only way then I will do it like that I suppose.

Comment: easy enough to implode/join only part of an array.

Comment: What method are you actually using?

Comment: @ErikReppen - Nothing yet. I was curious as to what the best approach would be.

Comment: @Aust What are you feeding the regEx as an argument into? How are you getting those results? Exec and match don't give me that.

Comment: @ErikReppen - Oh I see. I use the .match() function of JavaScript to get those results. `var str = 'Hey look at the lion!'; var answer = str.match(/h.*e.*l.*l.*o.*/i);`

Comment: I'm not understanding how you could get 'h' as a result for a match. There has to be an 'e' following it.

Comment: @ErikReppen - The 'H' comes from (H)ey and the 'e' comes from H(e)y.

Comment: Why do you want to return "Hello" when you've essentially hard-coded that in the regex?

Comment: @Eric - The "Hello" is just an example so you guys can see exactly what my question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using a regex. One of the unchangeable rules while using a regex is that every character can only be matched *one time*. That means you cannot return your whole sentence *and* some parts within it.

Example:

```
"abc".match(/a|b|c|(abc)/g)
```

The last `abc` group, although it would match, is never matched because the characters of abc match the earlier expressions of `a|b|c`

I do not know what you want to achieve by essentially hardcoding your result within a regexp, I assume that your *real* code should do something else. If not, just assign "hello" to a variable.

Comment: Bummer. It seems like I should be able to do something like `/(h<.*>e<.*>l<.*>l<.*>o<.*>)/i` and have the <> mark what I don't want to capture in my group.

Comment: Do you want to strip html tags from text? Just an assumption looking at your comment...

Comment: No I was just thinking of how it could be implemented in the RegExp haha. Anyways thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is fine. You're just executing it once and returning one match. Thats fine.

Look here for reference: http://regex101.com/r/jU3zU2

You can use backreferences as I have in the example to get the entire data, if you like.

However, you want to return "hello" which is what you have in the regex... so uh.. what?

Comment: No I don't want the entire data. I just want to know how to get the 'Hello' on one line instead of multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_shift($answer);
$answer = implode('',$answer);
```

The array_shift will remove the element that contains the entire string from the array of results then the implode will bunch them all together into a single string.

Comment: Not without you actually telling us what you're doing with the RegEx.